# How to get a "This server prefers ChaCha20" description on SSL Labs test with Let's Encrypt and Nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I find that in ["SSL Report: google.com"](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=google.com&s=216.58.194.206)
[image]
`(P) This server prefers ChaCha20 suites with clients that don't have AES-NI (e.g., Android devices)`
I tried to put all chacha20 ciphers at the beginning,doesn't work.
Then I tried to sort ciphers just like the report and it didn't work either.
How to sort the ciphers or configuration the nginx to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boringssl to compile nginx.
Boringssl has `Equal preference cipher groups`
Set ciphers like below,you can get it.
`ciphers [ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256|ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305]`

Cloudflare cdn services can also do this [Cloudflare sslconfig](https://github.com/cloudflare/sslconfig/blob/master/conf)

Comment: An important notice from boringssl's website, especially noteworthy given that it is a security product: "Although BoringSSL is an open source project, it is not intended for general use, as OpenSSL is. We don't recommend that third parties depend upon it. Doing so is likely to be frustrating because there are no guarantees of API or ABI stability."

Comment: Given that we're talking about security, and especially cryptography, using a less mature, less tested and/or unsupported library is actually a liability.

Comment: @jmng yeah,I agree that.I test this on personal blog.You can do it more simply  If you use cloudflare as cdn.

Answer (score 0):

That's likely because you are using an nginx version that doesn't support those ciphers.

Nginx uses the ciphers implemented on OpenSSL, and Chacha20 was only implemented in [OpenSSL 1.0.2](https://www.onwebsecurity.com/announcements/rebase-openssl-1-0-2-chacha-to-use-tls-1-3.html), so the version of nginx that you have installed likely uses an OpenSSL version that doesn't have support for those ciphers. For example, nginx-extras 1.10.3 uses libssl1.0.0, so it doesn't support Chacha20.

You can either install a [version](https://nginx.org/en/download.html) of nginx that supports a newer release of OpenSSL, or build nginx manually to include such support, like demonstrated in [this article](https://scotthelme.co.uk/doing-the-chacha-with-nginx/).

Comment: I'm using the newest nginx(1.14.2) and openssl (1.1.1a).